# Documenting php code - best way to document a group of includes or requires

Tags: php, documentation

Hi just as the title suggests i am looking for the best way to document groups of requires or includes in a php class file.  Should each require be documented and are there any phpdoc tags that should be used specifically.

Comment: If you're including classes, maybe you want to use [SPL Autoloaders](http://php.net/manual/de/function.spl-autoload-register.php). These dynamically load classes, when you are about to use them. This way you don't need to `require_once` classes, but simply can use them.

Answer (score 1):

There are many documentation tools available. you can try any of them.

JSDoc, phpDocumentor, OraDoclet, doxygen, phpdoc, PHPxRef.

I personally use doxygen or phpDocumentor

Answer (score 0):

All include and require files should be documented at the top of the file
Check out the @category tag to group them together.